# Installing mcrypt on mac php 7.1.16

Tags: php

I need to set up a magento site locally but during installation I'm getting the error 'PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.' I then checked for the extension by doing php -m and noted the extension isn't there.
I then tried to install it with brew install php71-mcrypt which didn't work so I tried brew install mcrypt @php71-mcrypt but I'm getting the error 'Error: No available formula with the name "@php71-mcrypt"'.

Anybody know how to get this installed or how to bypass the error for the magento installation?

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4826

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pixeline/51c43c787f51b018d484597f30be3d2b

Comment: Not sure why I am googling for you

Comment: mcrypt has been deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php#migration71.deprecated.ext-mcrypt

Comment: https://blog.pheonixsolutions.com/install-mcrypt-php-macos-high-sierra-development-server/

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anybody else I solved the issue by using a different php version for mamp!

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated was removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.